# Cannot build cmake project with including directories in cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

```
|---Engine
|----CMakeList.txt
|----Engine.cpp
|----Engine.h

|---Models
|----CMakeList.txt
|----Snake.cpp
|----Snake.hpp

|---Type
|----CMakeList.txt
|----Point.hpp

|---CMakeList.txt
|---main.cpp
```

I just can't tell the main sheet that I want to add a directory with files to it ...

Each time, errors of the following type appear:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 12 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "Snake" which is not built by
  this project.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 13 (target_link_directories):
  Cannot specify link directories for target "Snake" which is not built by
  this project.


CMake Error at Engine / CMakeLists.txt: 8 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "Snake" which is not built by
  this project.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 17 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "Snake" which is not built by this
  project.


- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Which, for several hours of intensified attempts, are not corrected in any way. Can anyone help with this?

`CMakeLists.txt` from Engine folder:

```
set(HEADERS
        Engine.h)
set(SOURCES
        Engine.cpp)

add_library(Engine ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Main `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(Snake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Engine)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Engine)

add_subdirectory(Engine)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Engine)




add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )

find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES FALSE)
```

Comment: You're trying to use a target (`${PROJECT_NAME}`) before it's been declared.

Comment: Variable `PROJECT_NAME` refers to the name of the current project, started with `project()` command. It seems that you forgot to call `project()` in the `Engine/CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors. The first one is to call a `PROJECT_NAME` that hasn't been built yet. `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` and `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME ...)` should be used before the `target_include_directories` and `target_link_directories` that refers to it. Because, as @Stephen Newell noted, otherwise you will be using a `PROJECT NAME` that hasn't been declared/built yet.

The second error is that you are calling a `PROJECT_NAME` inside `Engine/CMakeLists`. Maybe you are missing a `project(...)` inside of it.

Maybe you should move `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES FALSE)` before linking it, as well.

Comment: I changed my main CMakeLIst and right now its work good but i have another problem and it Type/CMakeLIst.txt

```  project(Snake)
set(HEADER
        Point.hpp)
add_library(Type ${HEADER})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Its cannot linking with main cmakelist and i havent an idea for solve this problem.

New main cmakelist : https://pastebin.com/tPts9kVu

Comment: You would need to also show the `Type/CMakeLists.txt`, which by the way you wrote with a typo ... make sure that your file doesn't have one as well